# Finding unconditional expected value and variance

Tags: probability, statistics

Given $E(X|Y)$ = 0 and $E(X^2|Y) = \sigma^2$ find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$.

I was thinking
$$
Var(X|Y) = E(X^2|Y) - [E(X|Y)]^2
$$
and then
$$
Var(X) = E(Var(X|Y)) + Var(E(X|Y))
$$
but I don't know if that is right.

Comment: It is right and should yield $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sigma^2\,.$ See the answer below why.

Answer (score 1):

Given $E(X|Y)$ = 0 and $E(X^2|Y) = \sigma^2$. Hence
$$EX = E ( E(X|Y) ) = 0$$
and $$  EX^2 = E (E(X^2|Y) ) = \sigma^2$$
so $Var X = EX^2 - (EX)^2 = \sigma^2$.